# redirect non-www to www for a specific subfolder only

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redirection, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect one subfolder of my website to www if its not having www prefix. For example.

```
If user opens example.com/sites
it should redirect to
www.example.com/sites

Also, 

If user opens example.com/sites/whateverlink
it should redirect to  www.example.com/stores/whateverlink
```

For some reason, I dont want to include the main domain and other subfolders for this redirection. Please help me to write a rule for this.

Comment: Which server software are you using? Each one has its own method for doing so (i.e. `RewriteRule` in a `<Location>` for Apache)

Comment: apache only. I know the rule for all domains. but not subfolder

Comment: If you want to restrict to a specific local file/folder, put the `RewriteRule` in a `<File /path/to/file>` or `<Directory /path/to/directory>` directive. If you want to restrict it to a specific URL, do so with a `<Location /url/path/>` directive. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: because of some reasons, I cant use the directory or location tags. Cant we write that with a rewrite rule ?

Comment: I think you could use a `RewriteCond` that would only match your chosen directories.

Comment: can u plz help on this

Comment: `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}" "^example.com/sites"` should restrict the next `RewriteRule` to `example.com/sites` (make sure you test it). Notice the caret in `^example.com`. More info: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: thanks for the insights. I wrote it in other way. Posting as answer

Answer (score 1):

This rule worked perfect. Posting here as it might help someone like me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/sites(.*)$ https://www.example.com/sites$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Should work better than what I suggested ^^ don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.